# *ngFor no muestra lista

Tags: ionic3

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let pais of paises">
  <ion-avatar>
    <img src="{{pais.imagen_armada}}">
  </ion-avatar>
   <p style="color: red;">{{pais.PaisD}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

ts
    (esto en ionViewDidLoad() )

```
bla bla bla
this.pais.loadPaises().then(
(res) =>{
this.paises = res['records'];
loader.dismiss();
alert(this.paises[0].PaisD);
alert(this.paises[0].imagen_armada);
bla bla bla
```

El alert muestra el dato correcto, pero en la vista no veo nada.
Consola no muestra nada.
cli packages: (C:\Users\guillermo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.8
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías primero realizar el `console.log("Paises: ", this.paises)` y así podríamos descartar. Segundo, ¿estás obteniendo dichos datos desde un API externo donde retornan los valores en formato JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar hacer lo siguiente, segun veo no tiene el  `<ion-list>`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let pais of paises">
    <ion-avatar>
      <img src="{{pais.imagen_armada}}">
    </ion-avatar>
    <p style="color: red;">{{pais.PaisD}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```